# EOF not working in while loop for getchar() in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c, ubuntu-11.10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef EOF
#define EOF (-1)
#endif

int main(void)
{
    int nb, nl, nt, c;
    nb = 0;
    nl = 0;
    nt = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' ')
            ++nb;
        else if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        else if (c == '\t')
            ++nt;
    }
    printf("Input has %d blanks, %d tabs, and %d newlines\n", nb, nt, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this code not working?

I compiled this code on my Ubuntu 11.10. If I replace `EOF` with `\n`, it's working as expected, but not with EOF.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working with EOF*?

Comment: Indentation, please ?

Comment: Number of blanks, tabs and newline is not coming as loop is continous how to stop it

Comment: You should accept one of the answers, it it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is a macro defined in the `stdio.h` header file. It's an abbreviation for `End-of-file` and marks a condition where no more data can be read from an input stream. You should not redefine the macro. It is a value such that for any character `ch`, the expression `ch == EOF` always evaluates to `false`. On a *nix system, you enter this value by pressing `Ctrl + D` keys. On Windows systems, `Ctrl+Z` produces `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Firstly do not re-define `EOF`...

Secondly, press `Ctrl+D` to exit your application. It works for me:

```
d@reference:~/tmp$ ./a.out 
a
s
f <Ctrl+D>
Input has 0 blanks, 0 tabs, and 3 newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine as it is.

To get an `EOF` on terminal input, you must press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> at the beginning of a line, e.g.

> $ ./program
>   Hello, world!
>   <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

Now the program receives `EOF` and terminates the `while` loop.